# How to integrate swagger tool with apache CXF REST web service using CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet?

Tags: apache, rest, cxf, swagger, swagger-ui

Could you please someone provide the clear steps to integrate with Swagger into Apache CXF JAX-RS application without spring framework support(using  using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet).

I have gone through swagger site and blogs I haven't find any clear steps for configuring swagger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did these steps:

1. Added required dependency to my project:

   ```
       <!-- SWAGGER -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
           <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.8</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
           <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.4</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>${slf4j-simple.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
           <version>${slf4j-simple.version}</version>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Updated the web.xml as mentioned here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=61318164
3. Added swagger-ui 2.1.4 as project resources (I edited index.html to point at the right url);
4. Added @Api annotation to my services cxf;

Hopes this help

**UPDATE:**

CXF dependency:

```
    <!-- CXF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

with cxf.version = 3.1.5 (CXF 3.1.X is only for jdk 1.7 or newer)

Comment: Thank you so much Nicola, could you please share the complete list of jars required for this requirement.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, I will try and let you know the update.

Comment: Hi nicola, getting exception as below:
WARNING: No operation matching request path "/swagger/rest/v1.0" is found, Relative Path: /v1.0, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: application/json, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Comment: All the jars and the web.xml configuraion is :                                               <servlet-class>
              org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.RestHandler</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.features</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature(basePath=/swagger/api-docs)
            </param-value>
        </init-param>

Comment: Hi Nicola, 
Could you please let me know where I am missing, I have added the mentioned jar, web.xml configuration and the swagger annotations properly but still i am getting exceptions as mentioned above. could u please share the complete configuration details if possible can you please upload sample project to github(https://github.com/). Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: when do you get this warning?

Comment: When I try to access the swagger docs using http://localhost:8080/swaggerapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/ url, I am getting the 404 exception.

Comment: Maybe you're pointing at the wrong url (seems cxfServlet url), you should point to index.html resouce of swagger-ui (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html)

Comment: Thank so so much, by using this "http://localhost:8080/swaggerapp/rest/swagger.json" I can see the complete JSON response including swagger annotated doc information but when I access UI using http://localhost:8080/swaggerapp/swaggerdocs/dist/index.html Swagger UI hangs on "fetching resource list: http://localhost:8080/", in the index.html file i have usd the same url "http://localhost:8080/swaggerapp/rest/swagger.json"

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I have accepted the answer but still please let me know why my swagger UI hangs on "fetching resource list: http://localhost:8080/swaggerapp/rest/swagger.json", in the index.html file I have used the same url as "htp://localhost:8080/swaggerapp/rest/swagger.json";

Comment: Are there some errors in log file? Have you added [@Api annotation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#api) into your service(com.rest.RestHandler)? Have you some rest method in this service?

Comment: In the log file I can see the request getting processed successfully, Yes I have annotated with  Api and ApiOperations, from the rest client tool POSTMAN  I can see the json response by using     localhost:8080/swaggerapp/rest/swagger.json url but the same response not getting displayed in the Swagger-ui.

Comment: Maybe could be useful to add the slf4j dependency for swagger log (see my first answer for slf4j depdencies)

Comment: Yes Nicola, I have already added the slf4j dependency and from the server side it is processing the request successfully but in the swagger UI the response is not getting displayed.Could you please share any sample code base through git repo. Thanks in advance.